# Want to make a DB call wait after a function is completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I want to perform this operation using NODE JS:

First Step - I'm creating a employee using a method and saving as employeeid.
Second Step - I'm adding a salary from the application
Third Step - I'm querying the DB to get the Salary added 
Fourth Step - I'm displaying that salary

However when I run this code, the query part happens at the start of the program before the salary addition itself and returning the value as empty.

I have constructed async function and calling by await from the main. Is there any way I can let the nodeJS to happen the query part to happen after salary addition.

Comment: show some code for a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: `const employeeID = await commonWorkflows.employeeRegistration(employeeData);<br/>
addSalaryToEmployee();<br/>
const salaryValue= await getSalaryForEmp(employeeID);<br/>
printSalary(salaryValue);`<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
                                                 







Hi @ZohaibSohail 

 These are the sequence of the methods I have created. In this  getSalaryForEmp is the function involvingDB calls. This DB call method is executed first at first, even before the employee is created and salary is added. Hence the salaryValue is printed as blank.

Comment: `addSalaryToEmployee()` running later than expected smells like a promise that you need to await. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes. I want the DB call to be executed once after the addSalaryToEmployee() is completed.

Comment: Please add the relevant code TO your question (not in comments).  We need to see exactly what code you have.  If your code is calling asynchronous functions, then show those functions too.